# TreeViewer package not working in ANTLR v4 w/ Java

Tags: java, netbeans, tree, antlr

I am trying to display a GUI of a tree I have parsed in from a pascal program using ANTLR v4. I have used this import to get access to the TV package:
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer;

However whenever I try to compile my java program using ANTLR is says that the package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui. doesn't exist and that it cannot find the symbol for TreeViewer.

Any ideas on why it might be doing this and am I missing something from my imports?
I am defining this TreeViewer in java with:

```
TreeViewer viewr = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
                        parser.getRuleNames()), tree);
```

Comment: Most likely, it is a problem with your classpath.  Can you post some code related to your build?

Comment: The other imports I have related to that work which are:
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

Comment: ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
            pascalLexer lexer = new pascalLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            pascalParser parser = new pascalParser(tokens);
            ParseTree tree = parser.program(); // begin parsing at init rule
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Is my code to get the parse tree.

Answer (score 2):

Running a grammar requires **antlr4-runtime** package

using maven :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
   <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Gui tools like `TreeViewer` requires **antlr4** package

using maven :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
   <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it:

I use IntelliJ IDE and I had added the Antlr4 plugin from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4-grammar-plugin).

Then in the project, under external libraries, there is an antlr4-4.7.jar file and the TreeViewer class is in there. I click on the class and then it was added to the project.